# Connecting to database on the server created in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

My teammate created a server instance in aws. On that server, he installed mysql and phpmyadmin. We are able to create database, query on the database using phpmyadmin. My problem is that, if we use add-ons like KPIBees in google sheet to connect to database, it just keep on loading condition. It stuck on never ending loading icon.

How to connect to mysql database inside aws server? I've search on the google and most of them points out on connecting to RDS DB Instance. But we have not created our database that way because we just install mysql on the server and created database using phpmyadmin.

Comment: You need to add some firewall rules at your AWS server instance in order to allow connection from your google spreadsheet account.

Comment: We already allowed the IP in MYSQL, even in HTTP, and SSH. It didn't stuck on loading icon, but it failed connecting.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

=================

We are able to connect to database by binding the ip address of the server in my.cnf config file. Refer to step 2 and 3 on this URL:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html